# Getting all class variables declared and their values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am try to get all class variables and their values for a running script while using evals.

Here is the current implementation

```
class_vars = eval("dir(self)")
for var in class_vars:
    value = eval("self." + var)
```

Though, this is not optimal and takes a long time to process. So, Is there any way to improve this so fewer evals are needed (Preferably once, getting all the values) to fetch all class variables and their values.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`? You can just write `class_vars = dir(self)`

Comment: Use `getattr(self, var)`, no need for `eval()`.

Comment: Use `dir(self)` directly for the first one, and `getattr()` for the second one.  You don't need `eval()` at all.

Comment: The idea of a properly designed class is that you *know* what attributes it has without having to query the object at run-time.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry for not being clear, these are called from a different script and sent as a message, so eval is needed

Comment: @JerseyDevil `eval` is extremely insecure. If the "different script" is an untrusted source, your system is vulnerable

Comment: @Wondercricket, The other script is trusted, only issue is the time it takes to execute